# Converting codons (base 64) to a base 10 number

Tags: python, numbers

In the July 2012 issue of "Mensa Bulletin" there is an article entitled "The Digital Brain."  In it the author relates the human brain to base64 computing.  It is a rather interesting and fun article with a prompt at the end.  Said prompt asks the reader to convert Cytosine Guanine Adenine Guanine Adenine Guanine to a base 10 number using the fact that Cytosine Cytosine Guanine Cytosine Adenine Guanine equals 2011 (the first codon set mentioned is cgagag for short and the second is ccgcag for short.)  Basically you have to convert a base 64 number to base 10 using a table in the article that displays all of the possible codons in proper order with aug = 0, uuu = 1, uuc = 2, ... , gga == 61, ggg = 62, uag = 63.  I decided to give this a go and settled on writing a python program to convert codon numbers to base 10 and base 10 numbers to codons.  After writing a quick algorithm for both, I ran it.  The program gave no errors and popped out codons for my numbers and vice versa.  However, they were the wrong numbers!  I can not seem to see what is going wrong and would greatly appreciate any help.

Without further ado, the code:

```
codons = ['aug', 'uuu', 'uuc', 'uua', 'uug', 'ucu', 'ucc', 'uca', 'ucg', 'uau', 'uac', 'uaa', 'ugu', 'ugc', 'uga', 'ugg', 'cuu', 'cuc', 'cua', 'cug', 'ccu', 'ccc', 'cca', 'ccg', 'cau', 'cac', 'caa', 'cag', 'cgu', 'cgc', 'cga', 'cgg', 'auu', 'auc', 'aua', 'acu', 'acc', 'aca', 'acg', 'aau', 'aac', 'aaa', 'aag', 'agu', 'agc', 'aga', 'agg', 'guu', 'guc', 'gua', 'gug', 'gcu', 'gcc', 'gca', 'gcg', 'gau', 'gac', 'gaa', 'gag', 'ggu', 'ggc', 'gga', 'ggg', 'uag' ]

def codonNumToBase10 ( codonValue ) :

    numberOfChars = len( codonValue )

    # check to see if contains sets of threes
    if len( codonValue ) % 3 != 0 :
        return -1

    # check to see if it contains the correct characters
    for i in range(0, numberOfChars ) :
        if codonValue[i] != 'a' :
            if codonValue[i] != 'u' :
                if codonValue[i] != 'c' :
                    if codonValue[i] != 'g' :
                        return -2

    # populate an array with decimal versions of each codon in the input
    codonNumbers = []
    base10Value = 0
    numberOfCodons = int(numberOfChars / 3 )
    for i in range(0, numberOfCodons) :
        charVal = codonValue[ 0 + (i*3) ] + codonValue[ 1 + (i*3) ] + codonValue[ 2 + (i*3) ]
        val = 0
        for j in codons :
            if j == charVal :
                codonNumbers.append( val )
                break
            val += 1
        base10Value += ( pow( 64, numberOfCodons - i - 1 ) ) * codonNumbers[i]

    return base10Value

def base10ToCodonNum ( number ) :
    codonNumber = ''
    hitZeroCount = 0
    while( 1==1 ) :
        val = number % 64
        number = int( number / 64 )
        codonNumber = codons[val] + codonNumber
        if number == 0 :
            if hitZeroCount > 0:
                break
            hitZeroCount += 1
    return codonNumber

val_2011 = 'ccgcag'
val_unknown = 'cgagag'

print( base10ToCodonNum( codonNumToBase10( val_2011 ) ), '::', codonNumToBase10( val_2011 ) )
print( base10ToCodonNum( codonNumToBase10( val_unknown ) ), '::', codonNumToBase10( val_unknown ) )
```

EDIT 1: The values I am getting are 1499 for ccgcag and 1978 for cgagag.

EDIT 2: base10ToCodonNum function fixed thanks to Ashwini Chaudhary.

Comment: what's your expected output for ``auguuuuuc`?

Comment: Just by counting i find ccg=23 and cag=27 , which is also found by your script. But: 23*64+27=1499, which is the result of your script. So for what i can see: the result is simply correct ?! It's probably a silly question, but: Have you copied the codons in correct order?

Comment: @Sonryell: your result seems correct for the given table.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary O wow, you are right.  There is a bit of an error with the base10ToCodonNum function.  Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does actually convert to and from base-64. I suspect you did not define the codons in the exact same order they did in the problem.

With the order you've provided for the codons:

`'ccgcag' = codons.index('ccg') * 64 + codons.index('cag') = 23 * 64 + 27 = 1499`

Which is mathematically correct, with the substitutions you've provided. To get 2011 you have to put in `cggcag` - so, are you sure you copied them in exactly the same order?

Comment: @Jakob S. and Paul: There was a repeat of uuu (one of them was supposed to be auu) but that did not affect the numbers I was using. I retyped the table and am getting the same answers

Comment: With that table, `ccgcag` simply does not equal `2011`

Comment: I think that the author either used a completely different table, in which case it is ridiculous to expect the reader to deduce his codon table or, more likely, it was a typo in the article.  The table given in the article is the most common order for the RNA codons but don't take my word on that, I am not a geneticist, just a physicist.

Comment: If that bulletin ever posts a mea culpa, I'd be interested to know

Comment: I have been getting it for a few years now and I have yet to see an errata page.

Answer (score 2):

I could not follow your code, so I made another implementation, but I got the same results:

```
CODONS = [
    'aug', 'uuu', 'uuc', 'uua', 'uug', 'ucu', 'ucc', 'uca',
    'ucg', 'uau', 'uac', 'uaa', 'ugu', 'ugc', 'uga', 'ugg',
    'uuu', 'cuc', 'cua', 'cug', 'ccu', 'ccc', 'cca', 'ccg',
    'cau', 'cac', 'caa', 'cag', 'cgu', 'cgc', 'cga', 'cgg',
    'auu', 'auc', 'aua', 'acu', 'acc', 'aca', 'acg', 'aau',
    'aac', 'aaa', 'aag', 'agu', 'agc', 'aga', 'agg', 'guu',
    'guc', 'gua', 'gug', 'gcu', 'gcc', 'gca', 'gcg', 'gau',
    'gac', 'gaa', 'gag', 'ggu', 'ggc', 'gga', 'ggg', 'uag',
]

def codon2decimal(s):
    if len(s) % 3 != 0:
        raise ValueError("%s doesn't look like a codon number." % s)
    digits = reversed([ s[i*3:i*3+3] for i in range(len(s)/3) ])
    val = 0
    for i, digit in enumerate(digits):
        if digit not in CODONS:
            raise ValueError("invalid sequence: %s." % digit)
        val += CODONS.index(digit) * 64 ** i
    return val

def main():
    for number in ('cggcag', 'ccgcag', 'cgagag', 'auguuuuuc'):
        print number, ':', codon2decimal(number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

results:

```
cggcag : 2011
ccgcag : 1499
cgagag : 1978
auguuuuuc : 66
```

Comment: I am not the greatest python programmer, I mainly use it for quick algorithms or to check an idea.  Most of my time is spent with Mathematica or C++.  So, my code is probably not the most clear nor the most efficient.  I apologize for that.  But it seems as if most people are getting the same answer as me... I am beginning to think it was a typo in the article or that the author used a completely different table than the one published.

Comment: @Sonryell: no need to apologize. If you ever encounter the right table would you mind sharing it?

Comment: With this table, 'cggcag' gives 2011. May be a typo in the original publication?

Comment: The right order is any table with ccg at index 31 and cag at index 27.  The rest of the list could be in any order which gives you about 3.14699733 × 10^85 different combinations (if i did my math right.)

Answer (score 1):

```
def codon2dec(x):
  codons = ['aug', 'uuu', 'uuc', 'uua', 'uug', 'ucu', 'ucc', 'uca', 'ucg', 'uau', 'uac', 'uaa', 'ugu', 'ugc', 'uga', 'ugg', 'uuu', 'cuc', 'cua', 'cug', 'ccu', 'ccc', 'cca', 'ccg', 'cau', 'cac', 'caa', 'cag', 'cgu', 'cgc', 'cga', 'cgg', 'auu', 'auc', 'aua', 'acu', 'acc', 'aca', 'acg', 'aau', 'aac', 'aaa', 'aag', 'agu', 'agc', 'aga', 'agg', 'guu', 'guc', 'gua', 'gug', 'gcu', 'gcc', 'gca', 'gcg', 'gau', 'gac', 'gaa', 'gag', 'ggu', 'ggc', 'gga', 'ggg', 'uag' ]
  if len(x)%3==0:
      x=[''.join((x[i],x[i+1],x[i+2])) for i in range(0,len(x),3)]
      try:
          return sum(codons.index(y)*(64**(len(x)-1-i)) for i,y in enumerate(x))

      except ValueError:
          return 'invalid input'


  else:
      return 'invalid input'
```

**output:**

```
>>> codon2dec('cgagag')
1978
>>> codon2dec('ccgcag')
1499
```

Comment: As stated in the question: "Cytosine Cytosine Guanine Cytosine Adenine Guanine [ccgcag] equals 2011" -> seems like your answer is not the answer ;)?

Comment: The values that you are getting are the positions of each codon in the codons list.  This is not the actual number unfortunately.  You have to use a similar method to the conversion of a hexadecimal number to a decimal number but instead a hexidecimal you are using a hexacontatetradecimal number.  Look at http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55785.html for reference.